# Change QTableView widgets horizontal size based on data

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtableview

I've been trying to get 2 QTableView widgets to resize with each other in PyQt5. The widgets are in a QComboBox and the layout is set to grid. I tried the resizeColumnToContents method but that just makes the QTableView's columns smaller in width.

How it is currently:

[image: how it is]

How it should be:

[image: how it should be]

QTableView 1 can have various columns or just one. I want the QTableView 2 to expand in layout so that it covers the entire space and QTableView 1 to be just the one column being displayed. Is there a way to do this? I tried using a splitter and dynamically changing the setstretchfactor, but am not able to implement it. Some clues or hints?

Comment: You say that you want "QTableView 1 to be just the one column being displayed", but you also said that it can have various column. So you want it to have a width that is *always* the same of the first column (no matter the column count) or to resize to the columns if they're more than one?

Comment: Sorry, to rephrase, I want to resize the columns. QTableView 1 can have more than one columns and that data is more important since QTableView 2 has >50 columns, so there's no way a qtableview can show all of that. But the columns honestly are not the problem here, I think.

Comment: Yes, the column count changes, as according to it and their contents the width required for the table will change. Also, do you create the gui in Designer or by code?

Comment: I use the designer and then convert the ui files using pyuic and import them into the main logic. I don't edit the pyuic generated files at all. If I have to make any changes, it will be done in designer or directly in main logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions.

If you want to use the QSplitter, allowing the user the possibility to resize columns, you could resize the contents after the window has resized. Since tables and splitters might need some time to adjust their sizes, this has to happen after a slight delay (an "event loop" cycle).

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def delaySplitterResize(self):
        if not self.model1.columnCount():
            return
        total = self.table1.width() + self.table2.width()
        leftWidth = self.table1.frameWidth() * 2 + self.table1.contentsMargins().left() * 2
        for s in range(self.model1.columnCount()):
            leftWidth += self.table1.horizontalHeader().sectionSize(s)
        self.splitter.setSizes([leftWidth, total - leftWidth])

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.delaySplitterResize)
```

Another possibility is to subclass the table and update its sizeHint each time the model contents change. This works by calling [`updateGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#updateGeometry) (which invalidates the sizeHint and tells the parent[s] to compute again sizes) each time the model size changes and the section are resized.

```
class MinimumSizeTable(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # an explicit minimum size is recommended
        self.setMinimumWidth(self.horizontalHeader().defaultSectionSize())
        # ensure that the widget tries to occupy only the width provided
        # by the sizeHint
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        # section resizing requires some time to "update" the section hints,
        # so we need to delay the call to updateGeometry
        self.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(lambda: QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.updateGeometry))
        self.verticalHeader().sectionResized.connect(lambda: QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.updateGeometry))

    def setModel(self, model):
        if self.model():
            self.model().columnsInserted.disconnect(self.updateGeometry)
            self.model().columnsRemoved.disconnect(self.updateGeometry)
        super().setModel(model)
        if self.model():
            self.model().columnsInserted.connect(self.updateGeometry)
            self.model().columnsRemoved.connect(self.updateGeometry)
        self.updateGeometry()

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        if not self.model() or not self.model().columnCount():
            hint.setWidth(self.horizontalHeader().defaultSectionSize())
        else:
            width = self.frameWidth() * 2 + self.contentsMargins().left() * 2
            for s in range(self.model().columnCount()):
                width += self.horizontalHeader().sectionSize(s)
            hint.setWidth(width)
        return hint
```

To be able to use this class in your UI you'll need to *promote* the table in Designer:

- Right click on the table and select "Promote to"
- Type the subclass name in the "Promoted class name" field
- Type the python file that contains the subclass, without the extension (for example "mytable") in the "Header file" field
- Click "Add", then "Promote", and save.

This approach can also be used with a QSplitter, but remember that, from the moment the splitter is manually resized, it will always try to keep proportional sizes based on the new position.

Comment: This works well, but there are some bugs, I'll post them in another question perhaps. Thanks a ton

Comment: Try to explain what's going on here before opening another question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use:
heather = table.horizontalHeader
for each column (col) in the table:
     header.setSectionResizemode(ncol, QHeadedrView.resizeToContents) #This will limit the 
    width of the column. If you want a column to fill all of the available space use 
    "QHeaderView.Stretch" 
Besides, you may use a QHBoxlayout and perhaps relating the width of both tables.